# How to add one empty line to the end of the file in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

How can I add **one** empty line to the end of a file using `lineinfile` module in Ansible?

The following adds nothing:

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /mypath/myfile
    line: "{{ item }}"
    insertbefore: EOF
  with_items:
  - ""
```

The following adds two empty lines (presumably a string `\n` resolved to an empty line and a default EOL after a string):

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /mypath/myfile
    line: "{{ item }}"
    insertbefore: EOF
  with_items:
  - "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to reliably add an empty line to the end of the file using the `lineinfile` module.

[`lineinfile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) is designed so that it:

> will search a file for a line, and ensure that it is present or absent.

Effectively if an empty line existed somewhere in a file the task will pass successfully without adding a new line to the end.

The only reliable method would be either executing a shell command `echo` or `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to **insertbefore** EOF? It should be **insertafter** EOF which is default. The following should work.

```
  - lineinfile:
      dest: /mypath/myfile
      line: ''
```

Comment: Before down voting, read what the OP wants. He wants to add one empty line. My solution does exactly that.

Comment: this will not work if there are already other empty lines elsewhere in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax also to add empty space:

```
- name: add configuration
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /mypath/myfile
    insertafter: EOF
    line: |
  
      example config1
      example config2
```

Comment: Beware, this works, but is not idempotent (running the same script once again will once again add the lines).